# How to avoid excessive hibernate flushes to DB

Tags: java, hibernate, usertype

I'm using Play Framework, with Hibernate as the JPA provider, and I noticed that if an entity has a Blob member, it will always get flushed to the DB, even if I haven't changed anything in it, and even if I don't read the Blob's value.

Blob is a UserType defined in Play. [Here's the source code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/Blob.java). The basic idea of the class is to save the actual data in the file system, and only save a pointer (a UUID) in the DB table.

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268617/7581), I gather that something in the Blob code must be making a change between the time it gets loaded from the DB and the time Hibernate inspects it. There's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82946/7581) that suggests it might be something else.

How can I change the Blob class to avoid the DB flush if no changes are made?

---

GreyBeardedGeek's answer proved correct. The current equals implementation returns true only on objects with the same identity, and always returns false on nulls.

Changing this:

```
public boolean equals(Object o, Object o1) throws HibernateException {
    return o == null ? false : o.equals(o1);
}
```

to this:

```
private static boolean equal(Object a, Object b) {
  return a == b || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}

public boolean equals(Object a, Object b) throws HibernateException {
    if(a instanceof Blob && b instanceof Blob) {
        return equal(((Blob)a).UUID, ((Blob)b).UUID) &&
                equal(((Blob)a).type, ((Blob)b).type);
    }
    return equal(a, b);
}
```

made all the excessive DB updates go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to actually debug this to find out, but I suspect a problem with `hashcode()` and `equals()`. The first thing that I'd check is the implementation of `hashcode()` and `equals()` in the class that you are persisting with the Blob UserType - make sure that they work consistently, and follow the rules - .e.g. if `equals()` returns false when it is used to compare the 'old' and the 'new' state of your object, it's going to get persisted.

Comment: I'll check it, but the first answer I linked explicitly says "It's important to notice however that Hibernate's dirty-checking is independent of the methods equals/hascode. Hibernate does not look at these methods at all"